# How to connect Android devices to HyperTerminal?

Tags: android, hyperterminal

I would like to know how to connect Android devices to [HyperTerminal](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/app_terminal.mspx)?

I am not able to find the port on which my Android mobile connects and which connection mode to use. On my [HTC Wildfire S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Wildfire_S) I have various connection modes like 'Internet pass through','charge only','disk drive', etc.

Comment: How are you trying to connect? Through the USB port? Over the Internet? Or what? You really should just run [`adb`](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) over the USB port.

Comment: I am connecting mobile through USB port and I am able to pass some commands to mobile by using `adb`. My goal is to issue AT commands like send or receive sms, call some phone number etc. Can we issue AT commands using adb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid Android doesn't expose its 'modem' via a serial port.

What you probably need is some kind of application, that will expose desired functions through either [XML-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC), plain HTTP or some kind of [IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol) based protocol.

Some of those apps could be [AirDroid](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) (here I'm not sure how easy it is to control this from a script), [RPC - Base](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.fhgiessen.ap.rpc.bc) + [XMPP Channel](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.fhgiessen.rpc.communication.xmpp), or [SMS Gateway](https://market.android.com/details?id=eu.apksoft.android.smsgateway) from APK Soft.

Or you can write your own app for Android and emulate a modem over TCP... (I don't have any experience in this, but expect it to be fairly easy).

Comment: thanks a lot for your inputs. I will try to find how to emulate android modem over TCP

Comment: You are welcome. Though I don't think you will find a tutorial or howto. If you don't already have an app that requires 'modem' it is a waste of time trying to emulate. You can use some already implemented protocol (http, xmlrpc) or implement own simple interface on TCP (simple commands with simple responses).

Answer (score 1):

There is a review of this in the XDA forum thread:

[*How to talk to the Modem with AT commands*](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1471241).

That thread show you how to send AT commands (ATC) with a remote terminal (USB connected to you PC), but it has not yet solved the problem of how to use a local (phone) terminal to talk to the phone modem. This is dependent on both the modem chip set used in your phone and how the phone is set up when connected to a USB port. There are usually some kind of engineering menu (AKA secret code) that you can dial to get the phone to act like a modem or PDA.

BTW. You need a terminal application/program to do any talking to the modem (remember, it's a two-way communication). So that's why you need a rooted device, since the rootkit usually come with *[BusyBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox)* (that includes the [`microcom`](http://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF422/busybox.html) terminal program). Otherwise, you have to write your own program.